How to make netfilter (nft) count packets on rule?
I'm trying to create a nft firewall rule on my Linux router that drops first three SYN packets arrived from some source-destination pair, but without success. My objective is try to avoid syn spoof that creates a SYN-ACK attack reflection to some destinations. Majority the attackers send only a one SYN and try next address. Dropping first two or three packets coming from source-destination doesn't avoid but minimize the problem. On iptables no problem because you can use the recent module and hitcount but it's not work anymore, because iptables now it's only a frontend to nft and the same rule that works on pure iptables simply does not work anymore with these approach.
